# How to link Html box with Javascript function to give the expected output?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to **link the input box with id="b"** (which is **inside** the *div id="but1"* .) **with the JS function**,to give the desired output(*which just counts inside an array*)..but my junior logic isn't finding any problems in the code,what mistakes did i do?

This is the second time i rewrite all the JS function,and i still can't seem to find what's wrong.

```js
function alert1() {

  let arr = [];
  arr.value = document.getElementById('a');
  let b = document.getElementById('b');
  b.value;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length <= 10) {
      console.log(arr[i].length + " ", "Mbaroi rasti 1");
      b.value = "Mbaroi rasti 1";
      return b;
    } else if (arr[i].length >= 11 && arr[i].length <= 12) {
      console.log(arr[i].length + " ", "Mbaroi rasti 2");
      b.value = "Mbaroi rasti 2";
      return b;
    } else if (arr[i].length >= 13) {
      console.log(arr[i].length + " ", "Mbaroi rasti 3");
      b.value = "Mbaroi rasti 3";
      return b;
    }
  }
}

alert1();
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="div1" style="text-align:center;">
    <div id="but1">
      <button id="button_1" onclick="document.getElementById('b').innerHTML=alert1()">Calc_bashkesia-1</button>
      <label><b>InputBox</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="Enter Some Input" />
      <input type="text" id="b" placeholder="Calculation output here" for="a" />
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I expect the button with id="button_1" to output the alert1() callback's calculation at the input box with id="b",but that ain't happening.

Comment: If you have JS, don't put JS inside your HTML, too. On the JS side, find the element using `var btn = document.getElementById(...)` and then use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to listen for events like clicks. Also, as just a tip, don't call your function `alert1`, give it a real name, ideally a name that reflects what its role is in your code. (And then don't call it manually of course, leave it to the button to trigger it)

Comment: So,what you're basically suggesting is to just add a 'click' event listener to the button using js? Thnx for the insight,i'll try it.

Comment: Previous to my edit, you had your JavaScript within the body of your HTML as text, not within a `script` element, which of course does nothing. I've put your code into a Stack Snippet to try and help things.

Comment: An `<input>` element  has neither `textContent` or  `innerHTML`; it has a `value`. But, as noted above, don't use obtrusive JavaScript. Also you have `arr.length` in your for loop, but `arr` never gets a length; for some reason you have `arr.value = document.getElementById('a');` and I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with that. So: what is it you're trying to do with this function?

Comment: @learner correct. Keep the HTML "script-less" and add your event listening on the JS side, making sure to include your script files with `<script src="..." defer>`, where the `defer` keyword loads the code "whenever", but _executes_ it right after the DOM is done, but before DOMContentReady is signalled, so you don't need to write your own "waiting for the document to be done" code, you can rely on all your HTML elements existing.

Comment: In my file the js code is inside the script element,i just forgot to put it here like that.

Comment: @David Thomas i replaced the **innerHTML** with **value** and now it outputted _undefined_.
As per the **arr.length**,it's length is going to be defined after inputting some text in the input box with _id="a"_,similar to pushing the values to the array.

Comment: '*As per the arr.length,it's length is going to be defined after inputting some text in the input box with id="a"*' - that's not what that code does; the `arr.value` property will, instead, be a reference to node. [Edit] your question to clearly explain what you want code to do, not what you think your code should be doing.

Comment: @David yes,now i see.

Comment: Are you trying to output different values based on the length of the string that the user typed in the input?

Comment: @Cat Yes i am,but that's the easy part for me.

Comment: I just noticed your response here after finishing my answer based on the assumption that the user would input a number. (oops.) I'm glad you'll have an easy time adapting to use the length of the string that the user enters in the input element.

Answer (score 1):

Change the onclick in your HTML to call your function.

No need for an array or a for loop either.

The `return`s I left in there aren't doing anything.

```js
function alert1 () {

const aValue = document.getElementById('a').value;
const b = document.getElementById('b');

if(aValue <= 10) {
    console.log(aValue +" ", "Mbaroi rasti 1");
    b.value = "Mbaroi rasti 1";
    return b;
} else if(aValue >= 11 && aValue <= 12) {
    console.log(aValue +" ", "Mbaroi rasti 2");
    b.value = "Mbaroi rasti 2";
    return b;
} else if(aValue >= 13) {
    console.log(aValue +" ", "Mbaroi rasti 3");
    b.value = "Mbaroi rasti 3";
    return b;
}
   
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="text-align:center;">
    <div id="but1">
        <button id="button_1" onclick="alert1()">Calc_bashkesia-1</button>
        <label><b>InputBox</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="Enter Some Input"/>
        <input type="text" id="b" placeholder="Calculation output here" for="a"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @learner, I'm trying to build my stack overflow street cred. Feel free to upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This example:

- Uses a full-fledged JS **event listener** instead of just adding an `onclick` attribute in the markup
- Changes names of HTML elements and JavaScript identifiers to be **meaningful**
- Avoids the **placeholder** attribute, which is problematic for accessibility reasons
- Moves styling out of the markup into **CSS** (except for a couple of lazy `<br />` hacks)
- Adds the **`number`** type to the input element, and includes basic validation

```js
// Identifies HTML elements
const button_1 = document.getElementById('button_1');
const numberInput = document.getElementById('numberInput');
const resultInput = document.getElementById('resultInput');

// Calls the `respondToClick` function when the user clicks something
document.addEventListener("click", respondToClick);

// The click listener can automatically get (as its first argument) a reference to
//   the click event that triggered it. For convenience, we'll call it `event`.
function respondToClick(event){

  // Gets a reference to the HTML element where the click event happened (the `target`)
  const clickedThing = event.target;

  // Makes sure the click happened on our button before proceeding
  if(clickedThing == button_1){

    const val = numberInput.value; // Contents of `input` live in its `value` attribute
    const num = parseInt(val); // Converts the value to an integer if possible
    let output = ""; // Declares a variable to hold our output text

    // Validates the input field (so nothing will happen if it's empty)
    if(!num && num != 0){
      console.log("That doesn't look like a number");
    }

    // Sets our output text
    else{
      if     (num <= 10){ output = "Mbaroi rasti 1"; }
      else if(num <= 12){ output = "Mbaroi rasti 2"; }
      else              { output = "Mbaroi rasti 3"; }
    }

    // Assigns our output text to the other input's `value` attribute for display
    resultInput.value = output;
  }
}
```

```css
#container{ text-align: center; }
label{ font-weight: bold; }
button{ margin: 1.5em 0; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <label for="numberInput">Your number</label>
    <input type="number" id="numberInput" /><br />
    <button id="button_1">Calc_bashkesia-1</button><br />
    <label for="resultInput">Calculation</label>
    <input type="text" id="resultInput" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**And here is some line-by-line feedback** on the code you had written so you can better understand what it was doing...

```
function alert1() {

  let arr = [];

  // Creates a `value` property on the array and assigns a reference to an HTML element
  //   to it -- Creating a new named property of an array is allowed but will cause you
  //   confusion.
  arr.value = document.getElementById('a');

  let b = document.getElementById('b');

  // Unneeded. In JS, we can do `b.value="a string"` w/o first providing this 'declaration'
  b.value; 

  // Since the last statement related to `arr` was `arr = []`, `arr.length` is currently
  //   `0`, so the `i < arr.length` test will fail the first time and no 
  //   code inside this loop will run
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    // This loop (if it ran), would be used to process each item in the `arr `array, one
    //   item per iteration of the loop. `arr[i]` would refer to the item currently 
    //   being processed.

    // Assumes the current item has a `length` property and makes sure that property's
    //   value (not the length of `arr` itself) is `10` or less before proceeding
    if (arr[i].length <= 10) {

      console.log(arr[i].length + " ", "Mbaroi rasti 1");

      // Since `b` is an `input` element, its `value` property is what we see inside it
      b.value = "Mbaroi rasti 1";

      // Returns the whole HTML element
      return b;

      // The other conditions follows the same pattern as above...
    } else if (arr[i].length >= 11 && arr[i].length <= 12) {
      console.log(arr[i].length + " ", "Mbaroi rasti 2");
      b.value = "Mbaroi rasti 2";
      return b;
    } else if (arr[i].length >= 13) {
      console.log(arr[i].length + " ", "Mbaroi rasti 3");
      b.value = "Mbaroi rasti 3";
      return b;
    }
  }
}

alert1();
```

Comment: Very nice explanation!